# What is the Taylor series expansion of $z^{1/2}$ about origin.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $z^{1/2}={re^{i\theta}}^{1/2}=r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}$
Now seprate into real and imaginary parts we have
$U=r^{1/2}\cos(\theta/2)$
$V=r^{1/2}\sin(\theta/2)$
Now $rU_r=1/2r^{1/2}\cos(\theta/2)$ and $V_{\theta}=1/2r^{1/2}\cos(\theta/2)$ So it satisfies CR equations and thus the function is analytic.

Now my question is what is the Taylor series expansion of $z^{1/2}$about $z=0$

Moreover what is the vavlue of ${(0+i0)}^{1/2}$

Comment: For a function to have a Taylor series at a point it needs to be at the very least differentiable there.

Comment: but it satsfies CR equation means it is analytic...Am i right?

Comment: It cannot satisfy that equation if it does not even have derivatives at that point!

Comment: (In fact, it is not evn defined in a neighborhood of zero...)

Comment: I have shown above that it satisfies POLAR form of CR equation so there is definitely some problem in my understanding.

Comment: sir please will help me understand that why $z^{1/2}$ is not defined at and near origin

Comment: If the function were analytic at zero, its restriction to the real line would have a derivative at zero. It doesn't. The polar form of the CR equation is not of any use at the origin, unless it is used with immense care — just avoid it.

Comment: but sir it satsfies all the conditions that are listed in the satement.If polar form fails what is the reason?And why is this function not defined in nbd of origin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38716/discussion-between-rayees-ahmad-and-mariano-suarez-alvarez).

Comment: One key observation is: the square root 'function' has the a branch point at the origin, see the first example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Examples

Comment: The polar form of the CR equations is only valid for $r>0$. (Polar coordinates are singular at the origin, since the angle is undefined there.)

Answer (score 1):

When you write $z$ in a polar form in an expression, you are not writing something in terms of $z$, but in terms of $\log z$.

You have said $z^{1/2} = r^{1/2} \exp(i\theta/2)$ but this is not a well-defined function of $z$ for example if $z= -1$ then according to the choice of $\theta$ you can obtain $(-1)^{1/2} = 1$ or $(-1)^{1/2} = -1$.

So this expression is only a function of $r$ and $\theta$ (or equivalently, of $\log z = \log r + i \theta$).

Now what you have written in terms of $l = \log z$, is that "the square root of $\exp l$" should be $ \exp (l/2)$.

Now $l \mapsto \exp(l/2)$ is a nice holomorphic function and everything, so is $l \mapsto \exp l$ and its derivative never vanishes, so by the implicit function theorem, if you pick some $z$ in the image of $\exp$ there is a small open subset containing $z$ where you can have a well-defined map $z = \exp l \mapsto l \mapsto \exp(l/2) = \sqrt z$ which is holomorphic.

But of course, $0$ is not in the image of $\exp$ (and of course $\log z$ and $\sqrt z$ can't be well defined on a neighbourhood of $z=0$). So whenever you use a polar form, the fact that it looks holomorphic, doesn't mean that it is holomorphic at $z=0$.